# Is hydroquinone illegal in the EU?

Tags: european-union

I read somewhere that the skin lightening agent hydroquinone was banned by the EU at the start of the millenia however my doctor in Ireland told me that one can get a prescription for it at 4% concentrations.

Answer (score 5):

The EU has banned all pharmaceutical products containing hydroquinone in greater than 1% concentration due to concerns over increased risk of cancer and mercury poisoning with prolonged use.

The US has banned all pharmaceutical products containing hydroquinone in greater than 4% concentration, and products over 2% require a prescription.